# R data.table get unique rows dropping some columns as well

Tags: r, data.table

How to get unique rows from data.table also removing some columns from result, where uniqueness is defined by values in more then one column? For example:

```
tbl = data.table( 
  reader_id = c(10,20,20,30,50), 
  book_id = c(1,2,2,4,5), 
  date = c('d1','d2','d3','d4','d5'),
  inf = c('i1','i2','i3','i4','i5')
  )

 >tbl
   reader_id book_id date inf
1:        10       1   d1  i1
2:        20       2   d2  i2
3:        20       2   d3  i3
4:        30       4   d4  i4
5:        50       5   d5  i5

ut = unique(tbl[c(reader_id, book_id)])
```

As a result I get:

```
   reader_id book_id date inf
1:        NA      NA   NA  NA
2:        10       1   d1  i1
3:        20       2   d2  i2
4:        30       4   d4  i4
5:        50       5   d5  i5
```

Questions:

1. Why result has NA values? How to get rid of them?
2. How to drop `inf` column from the result?

To have instead:

```
   reader_id book_id date 
1:        10       1   d1  
2:        20       2   d2  
3:        30       4   d4  
4:        50       5   d5
```

Comment: ut = unique(tbl, by = c("reader_id", "book_id")) see ?data.table::unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
R> unique(tbl, by=c("reader_id", "book_id"))[,-4]
#    reader_id book_id date
# 1:        10       1   d1
# 2:        20       2   d2
# 3:        30       4   d4
# 4:        50       5   d5
```

---

Or if you prefer to drop by name,

```
unique(tbl,by=c("reader_id", "book_id"))[,!"inf"]
```

Comment: I think `unique(tbl[, inf := NULL], by=c("reader_id", "book_id"))` is better

Comment: @DavidArenburg But this will remove `inf` from the original `tbl` as well. I suggest to remove `inf` afterwards: `ut <- unique(tbl, by = c("reader_id", "book_id"))[, inf := NULL]` doesn't change `tbl`. BTW, chaining is used here.

Comment: @UweBlock ok, you can do it this way too I guess. Yes, I see you are using chaining, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
tbl[,.SD[1],by=c('reader_id','book_id')]
```